# Find the optimal pattern

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a string **s** composed of lowercase letters, such as

```
aabaaababbbbaaba
```

and a positive integer **n**, such as `4`, output a length-**n** string **t** such that when **t** is repeated to the length of **s**, they have as many chars in common as possible. For the given example, the optimal output would be `aaba`, because it has thirteen chars in common with the target string:

```
s: aabaaababbbbaaba
t: aabaaabaaabaaaba (aaba)
   ^^^^^^^^  ^ ^^^^
```

and no possible **t** has more. However, for `aaaaaab`, there are two possible outputs: `aaaa` and `aaba`, which each have 6 chars in common with the target string:

```
s: aaaaaab
t: aaaaaaaa (aaaa)
   ^^^^^^ 

s: aaaaaab
t: aabaaaba (aaba)
   ^^ ^^^^
```

Either `aaaa` or `aaba` can be outputted, or both if you'd like. Note that **s** is not ever repeated; the trailing `a` in both repeated values of **t** is simply ignored.

### Test cases

```
Inputs -> Valid outputs
1 a -> a
1 aa -> a
2 aa -> aa
1 ab -> a b
2 ab -> ab
1 abb -> b
2 abb -> ab bb
2 ababa -> ab
2 abcba -> ab
2 aabbbbb -> bb  (ab is not a valid output here)
3 aababba -> aab abb
3 aababbaa -> aab
3 asdasfadf -> asf
3 asdasfadfsdf -> asf adf
2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyx -> yx
2 supercalifragilisticexpialidocious -> ic ii
3 supercalifragilisticexpialidocious -> iri ili ioi
4 supercalifragilisticexpialidocious -> scii
5 supercalifragilisticexpialidocious -> iapic
2 eeeebaadbaecaebbbbbebbbbeecacebdccaecadbbbaceebedbbbddadebeddedbcedeaadcabdeccceccaeaadbbaecbbcbcbea -> bb be
10 bbbbacacbcedecdbbbdebdaedcecdabcebddbdcecebbeeaacdebdbebaebcecddadeeedbbdbbaeaaeebbedbeeaeedadeecbcd -> ebbbdbeece ebdbdbeece
20 aabbbaaabaaabaaaabbbbabbbbabbbabbbbbabbaaaababbbaababbbaababaaaabbaaabbaabbbabaaabbabbaaabbaaaaaaaba -> aabbbbaaabbabbbaabba
```

### Rules

- You may assume the input will only ever be a non-empty string of lowercase letters and a positive integer no greater than the length of the string.
- You may take the inputs in any standard format and in either order.
- You may output a single string, or more than one in the form of an array, separated by newlines or spaces, etc.
- Your code must finish for each test-case in less than 1 minute on any fairly modern computer.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so make your code as short as possible.

Comment: This challenge is Zgarb-quality. Nice work!

Comment: I'm assuming only trailing characters are ignored? So you aren't allowed to ignore leading characters like this: `2 abb -> ba` where it's built up as `(b)[ab]a`: leading `(b)` is ignored, `[ab]` are matching.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Right, the pattern must start repeating at the beginning.

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
sZµṢŒrUṀṪµ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#FYyxEcJQDENXgmFo0lmWFiALcIzACJS5tCl@mzsG@VnEyD43T092rct5zPH9fZ6POV5zbOdxvfeqgicyEikqaaLAENMUTkGiQYAUka0hhNANBiX5zBvW6hq76bSdH7Putz8)

Wasn't expecting to beat Dennis on this one, so tried to FGITW it (after trying several possibilities; there's more than one way to make 11). I came in shorter, much to my surprise.

Takes the string then the count as command-line arguments. Outputs on stdout.

### Explanation

```
sZµṢŒrUṀṪµ€
s            Split {the first input} into {the second input}-sized groups
 Z           Transpose
  µ      µ€  On each of the transposed groups:
   Ṣ           Sort it;
    Œr         Run-length encode it;
      U        Rearrange it to the form {count, letter};
       Ṁ       Take the largest element (i.e. largest count)
        Ṫ      Take the second element of the pair (i.e. just the letter)
```

This uses the insight that the letter in each position of the pattern must be the most common letter corresponding to that position. We can find the letters corresponding to a particular pattern via splitting into pattern-sized groups, and transposing. The main reason this solution is so long is that Jelly doesn't seem to have a short way to find the mode of a list (I made several attempts, but they're all at least six bytes long).

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes, based on @Dennis' solution

```
⁸ċ$ÞṪ
sZÇ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#FYwxFQIBDEN3dCCAs8OWNFGAAlgY8IAAHgK4@TDCGSlpX5efn7b36@f7OG7P3/o6XM7bfb@9u5sZFIpluRSSKVgVQlJKHDBpAzWaJsxpCLKdsyyiPTVNM@m4PFYvpz8)

This is a combination of @Dennis' solution and my own; there was a five-byte mode in that solution, which I stole for this solution. (I already had solutions based on `⁸ċ`, but couldn't get below six bytes with it; I hadn't thought of using `Þ`.)

### Explanation

`µ…µ€` and `Ç€` (with the `…` on the previous line) are both three bytes long (the latter needs a newline), and equivalent. Normally I use the former, but the latter's more flexible, as it allows you to use `⁸` to mention the argument.

This makes it possible to sort (`Þ`) by the number of occurrences in `⁸` (`⁸ċ`), then take the last element (`Ṫ`), to find the mode in just five characters.

Comment: Nice job outgolfing Dennis with his own language! :P

Answer (score 10):

### Mathematica, 51 bytes

```
#&@@@Commonest/@(PadRight@Partition[#2,UpTo@#])&
```

Input and output are lists of characters.

Also based on the modes of the lines of the transpose. I believe they called the built-in for the mode of a list `Commonest` *solely* to spite code golfers.

Comment: At least it's a byte shorter than `MostCommon`...

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, <s>99, 73</s> 61 bytes

-12, thx to @Rod

```
lambda s,n:''.join(max(s,key=s[i::n].count)for i in range(n))
```

Same idea, but rewrote it to eliminate the import statement.

```
lambda s,n:''.join(max(s,key=lambda c:s[i::n].count(c))for i in range(n))
```

Original

```
from collections import*
lambda s,n:''.join(Counter(s[i::n]).most_common(1)[0][0]for i in range(n))
```

Explanation:

```
s[i::n]                  a slice of every nth character of s, starting at position i

Counter(s[i::n])         counts the characters in the slice
  .most_common()         returns a list of (character, count) pairs, sorted by decreasing count
    [0][0]               grabs the letter from the first pair (i.e., the most common letter
      for i in range(n)  repeat for all starting positions

''.join                  combines the most common letters into a single string
```

Comment: you can switch to python2.7 and drop the `''.join()` to return a list of strings

Comment: @Rod Dropping `''.join(...)` would make it return a generator, not sure if that's allowed output.

Comment: @L3viathan it need to be python2.7 to work, added to the other comment

Comment: Can you write some explanation of how this works?

Comment: Also you can replace `key=lambda c:s[i::n].count(c)` with `key=s[i::n].count` (probably)

Comment: @Rod A list of strings is only allowed in the question for if you return all possible solutions. That's what I took it to mean.

Answer (score 5):

### Python 2, 106

Now it's a different answer! I was thinking about one(almost)-liner from the beggining. Now even shorter, based on zip usage by @Rod.

Thanks to @L3viathan and @Rod for clarification about using lambdas as answer

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#LcoxEoMgEEDRPqfYsQKHKqUzXCGNbRpUSDayLAFMwMsbi/zyz3P6fnhD02JgVLeBTBUz04TBFOSQxTmlWm3Tf5SHvJGoWjdwnKCqBhhgx3jK3HsbxCjPLi4xARabCrPPgBQ5lf6ICUMBJ3oMcStCyqMz07xY93jia/UUOL5TLtvnW9veaqeuPw)

```
lambda S,N:max(combinations(S,N),key=lambda s:sum(x==y for x,y in zip(S,s*len(S))))
from itertools import*
```

Explanation:

`combinations(S,N)` creates all combinations length N from characters of S

`max()` have argument `key` which takes as input function to use to compare elements

`lambda s:sum(x==y for x,y in zip(S,s*len(S)))` passed as such function

This lambda counts number of matching characters in list of tuples, produces by `zip(S,s*len(S))`

`s` - one of combinations and it's multipled by `len(S)` which creates string that is guaranteed longer than S

`zip` creates tuples of characters of each string `S` and `s*len(S)` and ignores all characters that can't be matched (in case of one string longer than another)

So `max` chooses combination, that produce maximum sum

Comment: you don't need to use `[]` on list comprehension inside functions, also you are using `1 for ... if <cond>` you can use directly `<cond> for ...` since it will be used on `sum`, python will take `True` as `1` and `False` as `0`

Comment: @Rod Thank you! If I would sqeeze my answer more, it will transform into your answer, approach is same :D So I'm trying something different right now

Comment: Yep, just saying so you can use on your future answers :3

Comment: @Rod I'm still learning python and find that PPCG is a good place to learn tricks and little nuances. At least for python. Btw, I've just beat you :D

Comment: [¯\\_(ツ)_/¯](https://memecrunch.com/meme/1Y6CY/i-m-not-even-mad/image.png?w=479&c=1)

Comment: Switching to a lambda will save 7 bytes.

Comment: @L3viathan and it will not output anything. Would it be valid entry?

Comment: @DeadPossum [He meant this](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#LcoxEoMgEEDRPqfYsQKHKqUzXCGNbRpUSDayLAFMwMsbi/zyz3P6fnhD02JgVLeBTBUz04TBFOSQxTmlWm3Tf5SHvJGoWjdwnKCqBhhgx3jK3HsbxCjPLi4xARabCrPPgBQ5lf6ICUMBJ3oMcStCyqMz07xY93jia/UUOL5TLtvnW9veaqeuPw "Python 2 – TIO Nexus") (note the footer and the header) and yes, a [function is a valid answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?answertab=votes), if its a lambda you [don't even need the `f=`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8737) (unless it's recursive)

Comment: @Rod Oh, that's great! Not intuitive, but I'll accept that :)

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 94 bytes

```
(n,s)=>s.replace(/./g,(_,i)=>[...s].map((c,j,a)=>j%n-i||(a[c]=-~a[c])>m&&(m++,r=c),m=r=``)&&r)
```

Saved 3 bytes twice thanks to @Arnauld. 97-byte solution that works with all non-newline characters:

```
(n,s)=>s.replace(/./g,(_,i)=>[...s].map((c,j)=>j%n-i||(o[c]=-~o[c])>m&&(m++,r=c),m=r=``,o={})&&r)
```

The previous 104-byte solution works with newline characters too:

```
(n,s)=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>[...s].map((c,j)=>j%n-i||(o[c]=-~o[c])>m&&(m++,r=c),m=0,o={})&&r).join``
```

Comment: Very nice. I golfed a solution for reference when adding test cases and came up at 122 bytes, looping through every char, saving the counts in an array of objects, then building the string from that array.

Comment: Rather than initializing `o` to a new object, could you just reuse the array passed to `map` by using its 3rd parameter?

Comment: @Arnauld Hmm, I guess that works because the question guarantees lowercase letters, so I won't confuse the array elements with the counts...

Comment: I think `(n,s)=>s.replace(/./g,(_,i)=>i<n?[...s].map((c,j,a)=>j%n-i||(a[c]=-~a[c])>m&&(m++,r=c),m=0)&&r:'')` should save 3 more bytes. (Or 4 bytes by using currying syntax.)

Comment: @Arnauld Not bad, but I shaved a further two bytes off. (And also fixed my byte counts; a trailing newline was throwing them off.)

Comment: ... and another two bytes bite the dust.

Comment: ... or perhaps I should say they _byte_ the dust...

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
s@ZċþZMḢ$€ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#jVE7TgNBDO33FCnoCQF6LkCLRDqP7Q0DC0l2EthQ0uYWSIiGClFEikRBuMhykeXZg0LKzGg8z/bzm4@7dDb8Xm4@h@ft6vng5@mtXS@7dv3Rrt7hXGxev14OAS677qhHBRYVAzNAwVBwlGG2mL5z3hHGKI4NAdM/cpiEUklS7uIE1xVEy9FVvL6pbu/Gk2mdZvP7h2bxuGiQTvOJ1kxVLGsaxSqmWWRtJhERGXMczxMk9yCd7EM63Yc06CkG3iWBlEn94W4VLmsQZksIInA1qCEREoMCj1UU5UxBlJnV@CZnegEfykHx8/1ecAViL2BXgTqpoETwb3AkmKN2NhFbGlfBnYxhJ6od7spEajQxJqKWg7AUg35uHlm78vJebk3urHcydzTsbpn@Z5yX8TZGuewX)

#### How it works

```
s@ZċþZMḢ$€ị  Main link. Arguments: n (integer), s (string)

s@           Split swapped; split s into chunks of length n.
  Z          Zip/transpose, grouping characters that correspond to repetitions.
   ċþ        Count table; for each slice in the previous result, and each character
             in s, count the occurrences of the character in the group.
             This groups by character.
     Z       Zip/transpose to group by slice.
        $€   Map the two-link chain to the left over the groups.
      M        Find all maximal indices.
       Ḣ       Head; pick the first.
          ị  Index into s to retrieve the corresponding characters.
```

Comment: Does Jelly have comments?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
meo/dNd.TcF
```

Takes input as `s,n` and outputs as a list of characters.

#### Explanation

```
meo/dNd.TcF
         cFQ   Split s into chunks of length n.
       .T      Transpose.
m o/dNd        Sort characters in each string by frequency.
 e             Take the most common.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @obarakon*

```
Ç=VëUZ)¬ñ!èZ o
```

14 bytes of code + 1 byte for the `-P` flag. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@3@43Tbs8OrQKM1Daw5vVDy8Ikoh//9/UwWl4tKC1KLkxJzMtKLE9MyczOKSzOTUioJMoEhKfnJmfmmxkoJuAAA)

#### Ungolfed and explanation

```
 Ç   =VëUZ)¬ ñ!èZ o
UoZ{Z=VëUZ)q ñ!èZ o}
                          Implicit: U = input number, V = input string
Uo                        Create the range [0...U).
  Z{               }      Map each item Z by this function:
      VëUZ                  Take every U'th char of V, starting at index Z.
    Z=    )                 Call the result Z.
           q                Split the result into chars.
             ñ!èZ           Sort each char X by the number of occurrences of X in Z.
                  o         Pop; grab the last item (the most common char).
                      -P  Join the results (array of most common chars) into a string.
```

Comment: I think you can replace `gJ` with `o`

Comment: @obarakon That's genius, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 132 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
p,k=input()
b=l=len(p)
for i in combinations(p,k):
 x=sum(x!=y for x,y in zip(p,i*l))
 if x<b:b,o=x,i
print o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcoxDsMgDADAnVe4UyBi6xaVx@AqSFbBtoBIpJ8nyc03U5UC1PfaRXIDKiq1r0b9LxDr0a0zGHLIO1t1JkkFAmL4SkHi2Em42Tu7zcAI7Sh2vMIJzxv@fOaf9A60ZucMUILxwQ29hOHJaCXuIHMuMWJEjHHx7ws)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
Iôð«øvy{.¡é®èÙJðÜ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#FYyxDQJRDEN7hkHcGLBFHHsFJMQkSNfQcUJCV1BQ/wz2caI0z8/JPNe39vGu3/V2P45nbeNTr3pcaq91zuV0gCcyEikqaaLAENMUTkGiQYAUka0hhNANBiX5zBvW6hq76bSdH/MP)

**Explanation**

```
Iô                 # split 2nd input in chunks of 1st input size
  ð«               # append a space to each
    ø              # zip
     vy            # for each y in the zipped list
       {           # sort the string
        .¡         # group into chunks of consecutive equal elements
          é        # sort by length
           ®è      # pop the last element (the longest)
             Ù     # remove duplicate characters from the string
              J    # join the stack into one string
               ðÜ  # remove any trailing spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 245 Bytes

```
function p($c,$s,$r=""){global$a;if(($c-strlen($r)))foreach(str_split(count_chars($s,3))as$l)p($c,$s,$r.$l);else{for($v=str_pad("",$w=strlen($s),$r);$z<$w;)$t+=$v[$z]==$s[$z++];$a[$t][]=$r;}}p($argv[1],$argv[2]);ksort($a);echo join(" ",end($a));
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/279a92a6ac8467fb5220a8d697eab14d044b51d1)

### Breakdown

```
function p($c,$s,$r=""){
    global$a;
    if(($c-strlen($r)))  # make permutation
        foreach(str_split(count_chars($s,3))as$l)
            p($c,$s,$r.$l); #recursive
    else{
        for($v=str_pad("",$w=strlen($s),$r);$z<$w;) 
        $t+=$v[$z]==$s[$z++]; #compare strings
        $a[$t][]=$r; # insert value in array
    }
}
p($argv[1],$argv[2]); #start function with the input parameter
ksort($a); # sort result array 
echo join(" ",end($a)); #Output
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 84 bytes

```
import Data.Lists
f n=map(argmax=<<(length.).flip(filter.(==))).transpose.chunksOf n
```

Usage example:

```
f 10 "bbbbacacbcedecdbbbdebdaedcecdabcebddbdcecebbeeaacdebdbebaebcecddadeeedbbdbbaeaaeebbedbeeaeedadeecbcd"
"ebbbdbeece"
```

Split input string into chunks of length `n`, transpose and ffind for each sublist the most frequent element.

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 68 bytes

```
f s,n{seq 0,n-1|{|i|sort s/"",key={|c|x=s[i::n]x~=c,"";[#x]}|head}_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/roda#jVLBjtpADD2Tr7BSqQIpq8K2vdBm7/0GhCqPx4HpsplsJtmGEvrr1J7JUo6AmNjP7/mZiS8VhKI@BX6FZVE/rMbT6Mbg2w7CpzwvnvlYnkYahzJs3Hpdb4e/JRV5/m3zYdiexz2jPf88X17Q1XDKZqE5OFFyU@bw8AQ5jFD5FlzhwfpsNsO2hXUJm8ibu8VWsKYP@/mmmktts1pvP@aQF9BgG/hH3fGO21hZbhcLqUkph@9PSvGLbGZ9zdn5sgJUO8wkmKLH9yiCJoZgFE6xiXCMEzrBYFIq34mnGd1mwjWT0gDMReMC1L4Tgzc8OAu@75q@gz23vMg@q0Ak0zRGrf6D76giwWKo0FYRCtUtFK4oSJZGslzt9u7X8@Gl9s1rG7r@7fdw/HMclHkchBT6hluSkaoWd@7gQueIh8bpkJ6c74NSHYFzYnYnu3UgRXDeZV/u1AQSg6/3GmDjSIZn@cj9WINMyPHK48mSEhtLpAUriKRsWCNr0WpoJSO2LHJCY5mIWPnaTvsZeaFkGKd3aDhbLcHEVkhRSbGd2CBb0Vq5b0ms0YR1CETSsswkwylDrVmniBaIrDSrTEG1Jo2tGuq/UJwYtEEKs8dlWizUxUi/uGfXI21d3Jm0O@b2kejTEXkpvmKYZNO6GXOtRz7@Aw)

It's a function that prints the output without trailing newline.

This was inspired by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113619/66323).

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
►ȯΣz=¹¢Ṗ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9odXNr///ilrrIr86jej3CucKi4bmWwrL///8y/2FiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6eXg)

Zgarb-quality questions need a Zgarb language answer.

### Explanation

```
►ȯΣz=¹¢Ṗ²
     ¹ Ṗ² length n powerset of string
►ȯ        max by:
      ¢   repeating each subsequence infinitely
   z=¹    and check equality with the input
  Σ       sum the results
          this will return the most optimal pattern.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
òV ÕËü ñÊ¬Ì
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=8lYg1cv8IPHKrMw&input=InN1cGVyY2FsaWZyYWdpbGlzdGljZXhwaWFsaWRvY2lvdXMiCjM)

```
òV ÕËü ñÊ¬Ì     :Implcit input of string U & integer V
òV              :Partitions of U of length V
   Õ            :Transpose
    Ë           :Map
     ü          :  Group & sort
       ñ        :  Sort by
        Ê       :    Length
         ¬      :  Join
          Ì     :  Last character
                :Implicitly join & output
```